# MongoDB rich queries and isolation guarantees

Tags: mongodb

Asking for a friend.
Can we write ACID transactions that contain rich queries with MongoDB version 4?

If so - can I have an example or a pointer to an API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/ to start with

Answer (score 1):

It seems like we can do it with MongoDB 4.0: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/?_ga=2.98680029.215960757.1535643945-1204416970.1535643943

> MongoDB provides the ability to perform multi-document transactions against replica sets. Multi-document transactions can be used across multiple operations, collections, databases, and documents. Multi-document transactions provide an “all-or-nothing” proposition. When a transaction commits, all data changes made in the transaction are saved. If any operation in the transaction fails, the transaction aborts and all data changes made in the transaction are discarded without ever becoming visible. Until a transaction commits, no write operations in the transaction are visible outside the transaction.

Some examples in Java:
https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data

It seems like in java you can even set it up to manage transactions using the @Transactional annotation, like in Hibernate.
Just be aware that normally the usage of transactions bring an additional performance cost.

> In most cases, multi-document transaction incurs a greater performance cost over single document writes, and the availability of multi-document transaction should not be a replacement for effective schema design.

In my personal point of view, I would not go for mongo if you need to rely into transactions a lot.

Comment: But can I do several reads to MongoDB and then a write, and have the reads and the writes be in snapshot isolation?

Comment: I dont think so because it acts over the writes, it does not lock the reads as far as I understood. If you want to lock the objects during the read, the only way I come in mind is to set a flag lockForRead in the objects you read, set it as true when reading them and checking in all the writes that lockForRead=false. In this way, you will include the objects you read in the transaction.